# Comparing sql with c# list in query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-core, sqlbuilder

I have a problem with comparing a value in my sql database with a list of object in my code.

The object does not exist in DB

Example of an object in the list:

```
{
    public long CompareId
    public bool HasAccess
}
```

I'm using SQLBuilder in c#
And then I want to make a query that says something like this:

**In made up code**

```
SELECT * FROM EntityPermission
WHERE EntityPermission.HasAccess = listOfObjects.Where(obj => obj.CompareId == EntityPermission.CompareId).HasAccess
```

**In more made up code but with sql builder**

```
query.WHERE("(EntityPermission.HasAccess = {0})", listOfObjects.Where(obj => obj.CompareId == EntityPermission.CompareId).HasAccess)
```

I'm fully aware of that I'm mixing c# and sql here, but it was the best way I could explain what I want to accomplish.

**In words**

I want to find the EntityPermission where the HasAccess column is equal to the HasAccess property of the object where they have the same Id.

Really thankful for all help!

Comment: What is listOfObjects? is it another entity in your db? you could just do a join and get the data you need.

Comment: It's not another entity in my db, it comes from an input. So it's just a value that lives in that moment in code

Comment: What you are trying to do here essentially requires an inner join to a table variable or table valued parameter; the awkward bit is essentially: getting your `listOfObjects` down to the DB - how bit is `listOfObjects`? there's a lot of difference depending on whether this could be 20 vs 2000 vs 200000

Comment: the list of object can be around 500 entities potentially more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find the EntityPermission where the HasAccess column is equal to the HasAccess property of the object where they have the same Id.

So you have a table `EntityPermissions`. Every `EntityPermission` in this table has at least a Boolean property `HasAccess`, and a primary key in long property `Id`

Furthermore you have a list of objects, where every object has at least an CompareId and a HasAccess.

If I read your requirement correctly, you want all EntityPermissions with Id that is also a CompareId in your list, and that have equal HasAccess value.

So if your list has values:

```
{10, false}, {11, true}, {12, false},
```

And you have EntityPermissiont:

```
Id  HasAccess 
09  true         don't want this one, Id is not in the list
10  true         don't want this one, Id is in the list, but HasAccess incorrect
11  true         I want this one: Id is in the list, HasAccess is correct
12  false        I want this one: Id is in the list, HasAccess is correct
```

Normally you would use `Where(x => y.Contains(x))` for this. The problem is that with this you can only select on one property.

```
var checkValues = new
{
    new {CompareId = 10, HasAccess = false},
    new {CompareId = 11, HasAccess = true},
    new {CompareId = 12, HasAccess = false},
}

var result = dbContext.EntityPermissions.Select(entityPermission => new
{
    ValueToCompare = new
    {
         CompareId = entityPermission.Id,
         HasAccess = entityPermission.HasAccess,
    },

    Original = entityPermission,
})

// keep only those selected items that have a ValueToCompare in CheckValues
.Where(selectedItem => checkValues.Contains(selectedItem.ValueToCompare)

// from the remaining items, extract the original EntityPermission
.Select(selectedItem => selectedItem.Original);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the SQL WHERE...IN () syntax.

If you're using a tool that produces SQL, what you want to do is something like this:

1) get the list of values you want to compare

2) Create a string like the following from them:

```
"('value1','value2','value3')"
```

3) then produce a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM EntityPermission
WHERE EntityPermission.HasAccess
IN ('value1','value2','value3')
```

for an ORM like Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc, you can do the following:

```
var results = db.EntityPermissions
                .Where(x => listOfObjects
                           .Where(obj => obj.CompareId == EntityPermission.CompareId)
                .Select(y => y.HasAccess)
                .Contains(x.HasAccess))
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this with a table-valued-parameter and user-defined-type, then inner join:

```sql
SELECT * FROM EntityPermission ep
INNER JOIN @foo f ON f.Id = ep.Id AND f.HasAccess = ep.HasAccess
```

However: UDTs and TVPs are really very awkward to work with; frankly, I'd be tempted to just create two concatenated strings:

```cs
string with = string.Join(",", list.Where(x => x.HasAccess).Select(x => x.Id));
string without = string.Join(",", list.Where(x => !x.HasAccess).Select(x => x.Id));
```

and pass that down as parameters to use with `string_split`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM EntityPermission
WHERE (Id in (select value from string_split(@with, ',')) and HasAccess = 1)
OR (Id in (select value from string_split(@without, ',')) and HasAccess = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get your sql query in a result table then use LINQ to get your intended values. I know it is not most effective way but it could work.

```
        public virtual List<YOUR_DTO> ExampleOperation(YOUR_DTO dto)
        {

            sqlText="SELECT * FROM EntityPermission ";
            dbComm = db.GetSqlStringCommand(sqlText);

            DataTable table = this.Database.ExecuteDataSet(dbComm).Tables[0];

            List<YOUR_DTO> result = new List<YOUR_DTO>();
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                result.Add(new YOUR_DTO()
                {
                    ...
                });
            }
            //LINQ
            result = result.Where(obj => obj.CompareId == EntityPermission.CompareId).HasAccess;
            return result;
        }
```